# If i run npx or npm install create-react-app in my windows terminal. Is displaying error s

Tags: create-react-app, npm-install, windows-terminal

It always refer me to another directory in my computer and I can really access that folder. I was told to run npx instead of npm but but that still revert back to the former issues. Please can someone help me? am using windows terminal

Comment: I think you are confusing npx with npm

Comment: please don't post a link to a screenshot, try to post the message and code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using npm instead of npx.

You'll need to install npx, to do that use that command from npm:
`npm install -g npx`

And then, you can use `npx create-react-app my-app`

Sudo is a command common available in Linux and is used to run a command with Administrator or root permissions.

Comment: npx is built into npm by default

Answer (score 1):

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Comment: thanks dude. it works. i just uninstall the first one i install and the follow the command you gave.